# Looking for a CSS DRY-er

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've checked out several options for compressing/reducing size of CSS but what I'm really searching for is something that will truly DRY your CSS. As in it will take something like this:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; } div { width: 100%, height: 50%; color: blue; } p { color: blue; }
```

and output something like this:

```
html, body, div { width: 100%; } html, body { height: 100%; } div, p { color: blue; } div { height: 50%; }
```

Comment: Changing the order of selectors like that can significantly change what styles are actually applied to each element.  In your example code, DRYing it up *does* make it smaller, but using real world code might have the opposite effect (see:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/27910/26722)

Comment: Check out [OOCSS + Sass](http://ianstormtaylor.com/oocss-plus-sass-is-the-best-way-to-css/); it'll help you stay DRY for the developer rather than the browser.

Comment: Apart from what @cimmanon said: Now you have the selectors `html`, `body`, `div` multiple times in your desired output … so you are just DRY-ing yourself from another angle.

Comment: or get the computed style and save it! 1 browser at a time :)